# How can I remap Ctrl_Left + button to one action, and Ctrl_Right + button to another?

Tags: xkb, xmodmap, xbindkeys

In my particular example, I want to be able to remap `Control_left` + `n` to output `LeftArrow`, but also to `Control_right` + `n` to output `Return`. How can I do that? I red through `xmodmap` man, so as `xbinkeys`, and spent some time reading `xkb` custom layouts examples, but still this is question to me. What should I use, example maybe?

Comment: i don't think you'd want to create those definitions as part of the keymap (on the XKB level).  with XKB you could define the `n` key to output the symbols `Left` and `Return` on a higher level (think `AltGr` aka `ISO_Level3_Shift`), but mostly `ctrl` hotkeys are defined and acted on elsewhere.  `xbindkeys` may be a better fit.  note many applications use `ctrl+n` as a hotkey (open a new file or window, etc); attempting to redefine it may not work in all cases.

Comment: Left control and right control are two keysyms that are (typically) mapped to the same modifier: the control _modifier_ (not keysym).  So no, I don’t think you’d be able to make those mappings using only the control _modifier_.  However, you could assign ione of the keysyms to another modifier (hyper is likely to be free).  But then you might not be able to make to use that control key(sym) as a control key any more.